# For loop not printing what I expect. Need assistance

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, console.writeline

```
int marsHeight = ml.getHeight() / 100 * 100; // measure by 100s despite height value
int chartHeight = (marsHeight >= 1000) ? marsHeight : 1000;
for (int i = 0; i <= (chartHeight / 100); i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}m: \t*", (marsHeight - (i * 100))); // in order to print in descending order: (height - (i * 100)
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}m:", (marsHeight - (i * 100)));
}
```

I want my program to print out this if marsHeight is greater than `1000` (and it currently does):

```
[marsHeight]m: 
[marsHeight - 100]m:  
...  
1000m:   
900m:  
800m:   
...   
0m:  // this works perfectly!
```

Currently if marsHeight is less than 1000 (like 990)the program prints out:

```
900m: *  
800m:  
...  
0m:  
-100m:
```

What I want is this if it's less than 1000m:

```
1000m:  
900m: *  
800m:  
...  
0m:
```

I'm new to programming. Where am I going wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// First get the value.
int height = ml.getHeight();
// Now round to nearest even value.
int chartHeight = height / 100 * 100;
// Find initial value of cycle.
int forStart;
if (chartHeight > 1000)
    forStart = chartHeight;
else
    forStart = chartHeight < 0 ? 0 : 1000;
// Also you can simplify cycle.
for (int i = forStart; i >= 0; i -= 100)
    if(i==chartHeight)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}m:*", i);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0}m:", i);
```

The output will be:
if height 990

```
1000m
900m*
...
0m
```

if height >1000

```
1100m*
1000m
...
0m
```

if height 540

```
1000m
...
500m*
...
0m
```

Comment: This is really close but if height is greater than 1000 I need the chartHeight to increase.

Comment: so, if height less than 1000, then for statement start from 1000, if greater than 1000, then from height?

Comment: You are wellcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
int chartHeight = (marsHeight >= 1000) ? marsHeight : 1000;
```

to

```
int chartHeight = (marsHeight <= 1000) ? marsHeight : 1000;
                              ^
```

and if you want the output of to be same in both the condition like if it greater or smaller. You can make it like `Not Equal to` Like

```
int chartHeight = (marsHeight =! 1000) ? marsHeight : 1000;
                              ^^
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It solved the negative values issue, but I also need to change my if statement? Now it prints out starting at 800m instead of 1000m.